# What is the default successURL in recurly transaction?

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway

> I have subscription plans in recurly, it also provides the successURL
>   for every plan, which is going to be called after transaction is
>   completed.
>
> I have added that successURL into the javascript code as:

```
  Recurly.buildSubscriptionForm({
    target: '#recurly-subscribe',
    // Signature must be generated server-side with a utility method provided
    // in client libraries.
    signature: sign,
    successURL: 'http://domain_name/page_name',
    planCode: 'blablabla',... });
```

> so my question is, is i need to provide that successURL in this
>   javascript code for every subscription plan? or it will take automatically from recurly account?

Answer (score 1):

Your successURL can be any page you want.  Most people would start with the successURL as just a redirect to your users dashboard, settings page, or a thank you page.  The URL can be relative as well:

```
...
successURL: '/page_name'.
...
```

If you need to do some additional processing (like saving subscription uuid) for the subscription on your end, a success token will be posted to your successURL which you can use to gather more information based on the type of Recurly.js form you used.

https://docs.recurly.com/api/recurlyjs/integration#results-overview